# DISTINCT, SUM and CASE All together

Tags: mysql, sql

I have my current query something like below

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(lead_email)) AS total_today,
        IFNULL(SUM(
            case when lead_status = 1 
                then 1 
                else 0 end),0) AS subscribed_today 
FROM tbl_leads 
WHERE DATE(CONVERT_TZ(lead_time, 'America/New_York', 'Asia/Jakarta')) = CURDATE() AND lead_user = 5
```

in above query

```
COUNT(DISTINCT(lead_email)) AS total_today
```

is fine and giving me proper result

but for

```
IFNULL(SUM(case when lead_status = 1 then 1 else 0 end),0) AS subscribed_today
```

I want count only distinct lead_email same as my first part of query, I have tried various things but nothing working and giving me proper result

Let me know if someone here can help me for same

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share desired output with sample data? Do you need distinct email when lead_status=1?

Comment: Try `Count(distinct  Case When lead_status = 1 then lead_email end)`.  This will give you the number of different lead_email when lead_status = 1.

Comment: @ChrisMaurer I think he means the `lead_status` for each distinct `lead_email`.

Comment: What if the same `lead_email` has different `lead_status`? How should that be counted?

Comment: Note that `DISTINCT` is a _set quantifier_, not a function. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `COUNT(DISTINCT lead_email)` to make code clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery that gets each distinct `lead_email` and `lead_status` combination.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT lead_email),
        IFNULL(SUM(lead_status = 1),0) AS subscribed_today
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT lead_email, lead_status
    FROM tbl_leads
    WHERE DATE(CONVERT_TZ(lead_time, 'America/New_York', 'Asia/Jakarta')) = CURDATE() 
        AND lead_user = 5
) AS x
```